# How do I get grep to search for ebuilds with specific strings and produce an output containing only the ebuild's location?

Tags: grep, file-search

I have been trying to create a Bash script function that can be used to search for and open ebuilds with desired strings in Atom (the text editor). This is my current Bash script function (stored in `~/.bashrc`)

```
function edsch {
  L=$(grep --include "*.ebuild" -R "$1" /usr/portage/$2)

  for i in ${L[@]}
  do
    atom $i
  done
}
```

I would like to use `edsch .src.rpm x11-themes` to search for ebuilds in the category `x11-themes` with `.src.rpm` in them and then open the results with Atom. The problem is that `${L}` has contents that refer to where in the ebuild the string (e.g., `.src.rpm`) appears, as well as the location of the ebuilds on my filesystem (which I want to pass to `atom` in the `for` loop). Namely in this example `${L}` has the contents:

```
/usr/portage/x11-themes/redhat-artwork/redhat-artwork-5.0.8-r4.ebuild:SRC_URI="mirror://gentoo/${P}-${MY_R}.fc7.src.rpm"
/usr/portage/x11-themes/lovelock-backgrounds/lovelock-backgrounds-14.91.1.1.ebuild:SRC_URI="mirror://fedora-dev/${SRC_PATH}/${PN}-$(replace_version_separator 3 -).fc${FEDORA}.src.rpm"
/usr/portage/x11-themes/laughlin-backgrounds/laughlin-backgrounds-14.1.0.3.ebuild:SRC_URI="mirror://fedora-dev/${SRC_PATH}/${PN}-$(replace_version_separator 3 -).fc${FEDORA}.src.rpm"
/usr/portage/x11-themes/solar-backgrounds/solar-backgrounds-0.92.0.5.ebuild:SRC_URI="mirror://fedora-dev/${SRC_PATH}/${PN}-$(replace_version_separator 3 -).fc${FEDORA}.src.rpm"
/usr/portage/x11-themes/goddard-backgrounds/goddard-backgrounds-13.0.0.3.ebuild:SRC_URI="mirror://fedora-dev/${SRC_PATH}/${PN}-$(replace_version_separator 3 -).fc${FEDORA}.src.rpm"
/usr/portage/x11-themes/leonidas-backgrounds/leonidas-backgrounds-11.0.0.2.ebuild:SRC_URI="mirror://fedora-dev/${SRC_PATH}/${PN}-$(replace_version_separator 3 -).fc${FEDORA}.src.rpm"
/usr/portage/x11-themes/verne-backgrounds/verne-backgrounds-15.91.0.1.ebuild:SRC_URI="mirror://fedora-dev/${SRC_PATH}/${PN}-$(replace_version_separator 3 -).fc${FEDORA}.src.rpm"
/usr/portage/x11-themes/constantine-backgrounds/constantine-backgrounds-12.1.1.4.ebuild:SRC_URI="mirror://fedora-dev/${SRC_PATH}/${PN}-$(replace_version_separator 3 -).fc${FEDORA}.src.rpm"
```

The first part of each of these lines refers to the location of the ebuild on my system (e.g., `/usr/portage/x11-themes/constantine-backgrounds/constantine-backgrounds-12.1.1.4.ebuild` in the final line), while the second part (e.g., `SRC_URI="mirror://fedora-dev/${SRC_PATH}/${PN}-$(replace_version_separator 3 -).fc${FEDORA}.src.rpm` on the final line) refers to the line on which the string `.src.rpm` appears. Is there a way I can change the `grep` output so that only the ebuild's location on my filesystem is shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell `grep` to only output the filenames of files matching the search parameters, using the `-l` option:

```
function edsch {
  L=$(grep -l --include "*.ebuild" -R "$1" /usr/portage/$2)

  for i in ${L[@]}
  do
    atom $i
  done
}
```

This will produce the output you're looking for and open the appropriate files with Atom.